# yepnope 2.0 under IE 10

Tags: javascript, yepnope

although deprecated I still use yepnope (2.0) and enjoy it very much. I have run into an issue under IE 10 where it does not seem to execute the loaded script. See this:

```
yepnope.injectJs('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js', function(){
    console.log("script loaded");
    console.log(window.jQuery); // undefined under IE 10
});
```

It works well with yepnope 1.5.x. Any suggestions please?

Thank you, 
M.